# Sencha Touch 2.0: Universal Ext.TitleBar title not changing

Tags: sencha-touch, titlebar

I am trying to create a universal titlebar with a back button for my application. I am including it in the various views by using {xclass:mUserStories.view.titlebar}.

Here is the code for the titlebar:

```
Ext.define('mUserStories.view.titlebar', {
    extend: 'Ext.TitleBar',
    id: 'narwhal',
    config: {
        docked: 'top',
        // id: 'narwhal',
        title: 'CHW Module',
        items: [{
            ui: 'back',
            text: 'Back',
            id: 'backButton'
            // hidden: true
        }]
    }
})
```

However, when I try to dynamically change the toolbar when switching to different pages, the console.log of the titlebar says the _title has changed but the text on the titlebar and the "hidden" property of the button does not change.

Here is the code for the logic that occurs when the button is pressed to switch the page:

```
toPage: function (arg) {
    var t = Ext.getCmp('narwhal');
    var b = Ext.getCmp('backButton');
    console.log(t,b)
    if (arg === PAGES.PATIENT_LIST) {
        t.setTitle('Patient List');
        b.setHidden(true)
    }
    Ext.getCmp('viewPort').setActiveItem(arg);
}
```

I have also tried to include a ref at the top for Narwhal : '#narwhal' and use var t = this.getNarwhal(), but this does not work either.

I am not sure if the problem lies with where the id is being kept, how the id is being called, or because the page is not refreshing properly. Any advice would help!

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same situation in my project.

I managed to get everything to work like you want it by having a controller owning a reference to the title bar and listening to activeItemChange on my tabPanel.